# How do I resolve POST asp with REST-client on codeIgniter

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter, rest, curl

Im Lost Please, How do I resolve the following on CodeIgniter using
REST-cliente library (REST).

I try send POST, the webApp or WebResourse is based on (ASP.net), so the idea is this:

**getUser()**

```
function getUser($ID){

//set config of the URL 
$config = array('server' => 'http://www.example.com/app/webapp/);

//initialize
$this->rest->initialize($config);

//now here is my problem look at this Im lost, I try this but I dont understand:

$postData = '__VIEWSTATE=/DKEKCdmdaEKEKEcnaEKEqkencKJE&'.
            '__EVENTVALIDATE=/DWRRKCkadjeEWWrjrDSJEJeW&'.
            'buttonSearch=search&'.
            'textFieldUserID='.$ID.';

$this->rest->option(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$this->rest->post('query/user.apsx'); 

//When run this, I use debug but NO show ERROR, this only return content html of page     whitout query of user data.

$this->rest->debug();
```

Note: I user library rest and curl is named within constructor. I use this for request GET and work perfectly. but I want to do POST

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$this->load->library('rest');
```

The library:
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

Thanks.!!!

Comment: Just for being sure, did you try to launch a post with a simple curl request or with postman (chrome extension) and you got an answer? I mean, are you sure the problem is not in the REST API server?

Comment: Sure..I try the url on postman extension..this working perfectly...but I think my error is : $this->rest->option(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

Comment: Ok, use $this->rest->debug(); and then paste the result here to know what the errors are, :D

Comment: could you paste the answer from $this->rest->debug()?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in your question:

> //When run this, I use debug but NO show ERROR, this only return
> content html of page whitout query of user data.
>
> $this->rest->debug();

So, if you received HTML but not the desired data, the problem is the server you are asking to. It's more than sure that you're not doing the right request, but is weird because they should show you what is wrong.

Other thing would be, could you paste the given answer? Just to know what are the errors, if any.